# 2n boys are divided into two equal subgroups, find the probability that the two tallest are in the same subgroup

Tags: probability

If 2n boys are divided into two equal subgroups randomly, find the probability that the two tallest boys are in the same subgroup.

Here is what I though:
There are $$\frac{2n!}{n!\cdot n!\cdot2!}$$ ways to divide 2n boys into two subgroups.
The tallest two will be in one group, thus the rest of boys have $$\begin{pmatrix}2n-2 \\n-2\end{pmatrix}$$ possibilities.
So my answer is $$\frac{\begin{pmatrix}2n-2 \\n-2\end{pmatrix}}{\frac{2n!}{n!\cdot n!\cdot2!}}$$
I'm not really sure how to simplify this, and it seems too complicated to be the right answer...
Is there anywhere I made a mistake or any other easier way to do this problem?

Answer (score 5):

It's not that hard.  Say the tallest boys are A and B, and the groups are picked by lining them all up and dividing the first $n$ from the second $n$.  Then WLOG A is in the first $n$.  Then it is equally likely for B to be in any of the remaining $2n-1$ spots, of which $n-1$ would place him in the same group as A.  So the probability is $\boxed{\frac{n-1}{2n-1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should have written $(2n)!$ since your denominator should be 
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$
while $2n! = 2 \cdot n!$.  Otherwise, your answer is correct.
\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{2n - 2}{n - 2}}{\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!2!}} & = \frac{(2n - 2)!}{(n - 2)!n!} \cdot \frac{n!n!2!}{(2n)!}\\
& = \frac{\color{orange}{(2n - 2)!}}{\color{green}{(n - 2)!}\color{blue}{n!}} \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{n!}n(n - 1)\color{green}{(n - 2)!} \cdot 2}{(2n)(2n - 1)\color{orange}{(2n - 2)!}}\\
& = \frac{\color{red}{2n}(n - 1)}{\color{red}{2n}(2n - 1)}\\
& = \frac{n - 1}{2n - 1}
\end{align*}
Notice that the simplified form agrees with the answer provided by Cyclicduck.